# Installshield LE registering an unwanted .dll

Tags: deployment, installshield, installshield-le

Is there any way to prevent Installshield LE from registering an Acrobat dll during product installation? This dll in particular is a dependency of one of the project dependencies, so I don't have direct control over it. During installation it gives a "failed to register" error message even though the installation completes, presumably because it is already on the system (I guess, not sure about that), and it also fails to unregister during uninstallation.

Removing that error message would be handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I had to remove the dependency manually from the dependency list of the Primary Output group.